# Operator that kill the wave function

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, differential-operators, d-modules

I have the following function in $x$. 
 $\sum_{d=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\hbar^d}\frac{1}{d!}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{d-1}(1+i\hbar)^{m}\right)x^d$

I need a differential operator involving $(x,\frac{d}{dx},h,m)$ that is can be a polynomial in this 4 terms such that it annihilates the wave function. Or can give a proof that there does not exist such operator. I feel that there should be one.

Comment: Can you put parentheses for what is in the product? Describe some of the degenerate cases like m=0 too.

Comment: For m=0 it is $exp(\frac{x}{h})$ hence the operator that annihilate it is $h\frac{d}{dx}-1$.